# Modify this sub random number generator sub to exclude certain numbers

Tags: excel, vba, random

I'm new to Excel VBA. The project I'm working on deals with ranges of random numbers. I have five ranges and found this code which works really well for not getting any duplicates in a range:

```
Public Sub generateRandNum()
    'Define your variabiles
    lowerbound = 1
    upperbound = 20000
    Set randomrange = Range("A1:C5000")
    
    randomrange.Clear
    For Each rng1 In randomrange
        counter = counter + 1
    Next
    
    If counter > upperbound - lowerbound + 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Number of cells > number of unique random numbers")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each Rng In randomrange
        randnum = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
        Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(randomrange, randnum) >= 1
            randnum = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
        Loop
        Rng.Value = randnum
    Next
End Sub
```

The next part of the project involves the excluding one number (not random) from the second set and two numbers (also not random) from the fourth set.

I've searched all over Google, looked at a number of forums, but either the code looks really long or I can't quite understand it enough to modify it for my needs.

It has to be in VBA because the number generator works off of a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `Dictionary` object to store "forbidden" numbers for each single column

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub generateRandNum()
    'Define your variabiles
    Dim lowerbound  As Long, _
        upperbound  As Long
    lowerbound = 1
    upperbound = 20 '20000
    
    
    'define forbidden numbers for each single column
    Dim forbiddenNumbersDict As Object
        Set forbiddenNumbersDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            With forbiddenNumbersDict
                .Add 2, Array(1, 4, 9) ' column 2 forbidden numbers
                .Add 3, Array(2, 5, 7) ' column 3 forbidden numbers
                '....
            End With
    
    Dim randomrange As Range
    Set randomrange = Range("A1:C5")
    randomrange.Clear
    
    Dim counter As Long
        counter = randomrange.Count
    
    If counter > upperbound - lowerbound + 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Number of cells > number of unique random numbers")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In randomrange
    
        Dim rngColIndex As Long
            rngColIndex = rng.Column ' locate the current column
            
        Dim randnum As Long
        randnum = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
            Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(randomrange, randnum) >= 1 _
                     Or Not IsError(Application.Match(randnum, forbiddenNumbersDict(rngColIndex), 0)) ' added the condition to exclude forbidden numbers for the current column
                randnum = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
            Loop
                rng.Value = randnum
    Next
End Sub
```

BTW, your algorithm is quite inefficient

Comment: Thanks user3598756! I haven't been able to get back to this since I posted the question, but I will try it out!

Comment: I did get it figured out and you answer really helped @user3598756. Thanks a lot!